# code pulled from git removed my updates in same file (local)

Tags: git, git-merge, git-stash

I have pulled my code from git. I know that some conflicts may happen. So I did the following commands for git pull.

```
sudo git pull
```

...which did a fast-forward.
Then I moved my local changes to buffer using

```
 sudo git stash
```

Then I pulled new code from git

```
sudo git pull
```

...and got told I was already up-to-date.
Then I merged my new changes with new git code

```
sudo git stash pop
```

So now problem is, when I check my files all are those git files I couldn't find my changes that I stashed (my local instance updates not merged with my git code).

Comment: You spent time trying to hide text, but 90% of it is still readable. Just so you know.

Comment: Why are all your `git` commands being run with `sudo`? Also, I don't quite understand the problem. You popped the stash, and you now have your local changes back, it seems? The modified files after your `stash pop` are different from the files updated during your `pull`, so it seems the stashing worked properly?

Comment: but my layout went wrong

Comment: Your layout went wrong? Can you be more specific? If you `stash pop` after a `pull`, your local changes were applied *on top of* the changes that were applied during the `pull`. So if by "my layout went wrong" you mean your web pages look different, you need to examine the changes made remotely by your co-workers, and remedy things.

Comment: one more guy committed  before me and both of us have some ailgnment problem .Now i can see the same alignment issues in his page. We are working on same files

Comment: Your first `git pull` was a fast forward, so you didn't have any local changes.

Comment: @user3755198 Okay, so what happened is clear, then?

Comment: my alignment was correct but when i puled code from git .my new alignment changes are not these instead i can see the other guys code only

Comment: Where are the screenshots you have attached..?? Also, did you get any conflicts when git stash pop..? if not so, do "git status". check whether all your changes exist or not.

Comment: When you popped your stash it should have applied your local changes. I second @Breenho's suggestion to see what `git status` tells you. According to the output of your `stash pop`, your local changes are still there.